# FieldError at/. Cannot resolve keyword 'textField' into field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to do a filter method for my django application. I have some fields in db like, userName,designation,employeeID etc . Now i am trying to do a filtering; where there is drop down shows all the fields (name, designation, employeeID etc) and a text area for inputing some text. The filtering should be done based on the drop down choice selection and the data entered in the text area. While doing this i got this error: **FieldError at /filter/
Cannot resolve keyword 'textField' into field. Choices are: contactNumber, dateOfJoin, designation, employeeID, id, project, userName** I will paste my html and views.py here. Please help me to solve this.

```
<form action="http://10.1.0.90:8080/filter/" method="POST">
Filter By: 
<select name="choices" onsubmit="document.forms[0].submit()" >
    <option value="">Select A Choice</option>
    <option value="Name">Name</option> 
    <option value="Designation" >Designation</option>
    <option value="EmployeeID" >EmployeeID</option>
    <option value="Project" >Project</option>
    <option value="Date Of Join" >Date Of Join</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" name="textField">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

{%for data in newData%}
{{ data.userName}}<br>
{%endfor%}
```

**THIS is my VIEWS.PY**

```
def filter(request):     
    val2=request.POST.get('choices')
    val3=request.POST.get('textField')
    print val2,val3
    newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(choices=request.POST.get('choices'),textField=request.POST.get('textField'))
    return render_to_response('filter.html',{'newData':newData,'val2':val2,'val3':val3})
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class EmployeeDetails(models.Model):
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    employeeID = models.IntegerField()
    contactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dateOfJoin=models.TextField()
```

I am quite new to Django. Please help me to solve this

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do. You don't seem to have a field called `textField` in your model, so what exactly are you trying to filter against? It would help to post the model code anyway.

Comment: Where are you getting the value of 'designation' from the POST? I don't see it in your code. Also, are you sure that EmployeeDetails has a field named 'textField' (check the caps maybe)?

Comment: thanks for the reply ..i have updated the question with my model code. I dont have a field in model named textField or choice. I am getting the values for filtering in the variables choice and textField after POST. How can i get it filtered from all my db data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you expecting django to be able to magically map a field name to the names you specify in your template? For example, there's nothing in your model called any of the items you list in your `<select>` options.

I find the error very self explanatory:

> FieldError at /filter/ Cannot resolve
>   keyword 'textField' into field.
>   Choices are: contactNumber,
>   dateOfJoin, designation, employeeID,
>   id, project, userName

You don't have a `textField` field in your model, yet you are trying to filter against it.

Imagine `SELECT textField FROM mytable` -- `textField` just doesn't exist.

> ... and a text area for inputing some
>   text.

---

As for fixing your problem, you have several. You are trying to do a lookup on a specific field specified in choices, but there is no relationship between Choices and your fields.

To make this easy on yourself, at least set the values for your `<option>` tags **as the field names.**

```
<select name="choices" onsubmit="document.forms[0].submit()" >
    <option value="">Select A Choice</option>
    <option value="userName">Name</option> 
    <option value="designation" >Designation</option>
    <option value="employeeID" >EmployeeID</option>
    <option value="project" >Project</option>
    <option value="dateOfJoin" >Date Of Join</option> 
</select>

if request.GET.get('choices'):
    # prevent query on field ''
    EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(**{request.GET.get('choices'): \
          request.GET.get('textField')})
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand what you are trying to do, you are using filter the wrong way. To filter on a dynamic posted field(val2) with a given query(val3) try.

```
kwargs = {}
kwargs[val2] = val3

newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

the option values in you code would need to map the model for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have one field called "textField" you can't filter your "EmployeeDetails" models. You only can filter the "EmployeeDetails" models with available fields how: "contactNumber, dateOfJoin, designation, employeeID, id, project, userName".

=)